# Perl SOAP::Lite call fails

Tags: perl, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a Soap Webservice.I have to pass the name of a Code table (for eg STATE_CODES)  and it returns key value pair like NY - New york, DE-Delaware etc.

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw<Dumper>;

#use SOAP::Lite trace=>'all';
use SOAP::Lite +trace =>'debug';
#use SOAP::Lite;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

#my $wsdl               = 'https://dev1:2001/ACTS?wsdl';
my $endpoint    = 'https://qa1:2001/ACTS';
my $wsdl        = 'HTTPS://QA1:2001/ACTS?wsdl';
my $method_name = 'impl:getCodes';
my $uri         = 'http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj';
my $ns          = 'http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj';

my $client = SOAP::Lite->new(
              proxy=>$endpoint,
              service=>$wsdl,
              readable=>1
            );
    $client->outputxml(1);
    $client->envprefix('soapenv');
    $client->ns($uri,'impl');
    $client->outputxml('true');

my @param;
push @param, SOAP::Data->name("codeTable"=>'STATE_CODES');

my $soapResp = $client->call($method_name,@param);
print $soapResp;
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
[root@np1 ~]# perl /test/soaptest6.pl
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: POST https://qa1:2001/ACTS HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
Content-Length: 580
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj#getCodes"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:impl="http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <impl:getCodes>
      <codeTable xsi:type="xsd:string">STATE_CODES</codeTable>
    </impl:getCodes>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2020 02:46:04 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.248.33:2001
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /CN=qa1
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /CN=qa1
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The soap request kind of looks good, but it gives error. I pasted the soap request into SOAPUI and it gave error. But as soon as i removed the line before the xml tag. in the soapAction, the request worked.

Why is my soap request resulting in failure. is it because of some certificate issue. i believe i have asked the code to skip certificate validation and Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified in output above is just a warning and can be ignored.

Comment: Sorry, which line did you remove to get something working?

Comment: There's not much we can do; we have no idea what the server expects, and we don't have the server's logs to get a useful error message. My only guess is that you used a `{}codeTable` element where you should have used a `{http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj}codeTable` element (meaning `codeTable` might need to be `impl:codeTable`).

Comment: Re "*is it because of some certificate issue*", Not likely, though skipping the check is rather silly. "Howdy stranger. Let me tell you secrets, but let's use a code so noone else can understand us." What's the point of using encryption if you don't check to whom you're talking?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with java?

Comment: I believe the soap request is good. When i paste the below request in SOAPUI without the 1st two lines of SOAPAction and Blank line it works. <br>SOAPAction: "http://impl.webservice.acts.ito.aoc.nj#getCodes"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
......
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: I am a newbie to Perl. I am trying to bypass cert, to avoid complexity for now and focus on code. in my final implementation i will use the certificates